# WPF play "Click" animation on button. Simulate click from code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have 10 default WPF buttons.

In some specific cases I have to emulate\play animation of click on button from my view model. (Application in demo mode and demonstrating for a user how its works.)

I have no idea how to imitate default button click, any ideas?

Comment: Just call the method?

Comment: @Viv i cannot find .Click(); method in a button...

Comment: @Viv now i see it. How its possible to fire this part of code from MVVM without any specific MVVM libs? As i see only one way to pass delegate or view instance.

Comment: use a `Behavior`? have a behavior which takes the property from the VM as a binding to a DP in it and then on the propertyChangedCallback of that DP, invoke the click accordingly?

Comment: @Viv maybe... You can write all this like an answer.

Comment: well does this answer your question? isn't simulating the Click animation your actual Question? AFAIK calling a `RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent))` on a button invokes the Click event but not the underlying animation.

Comment: @Viv I thought that animation also will be fired. If no - this is bad that(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the UI Automation Framework (System.Windows.Automation) to be able to Click on a button via code.

```
var element = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
                TreeScope.Descendants,
                new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Start", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase))
            );
var pattern = (InvokePattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
pattern.Invoke();
```

This code will click the windows start button fro your WPF app. You can search for a button in your app the same way.

References required: UIAutomationClient, UIAutomationTypes

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want to get. You can set default style for all the buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        ...
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Then i can bind IsPressed property to my viewmodel to call this animation from code?

Comment: I dont see public property IsPressed.

Comment: Try to change `Button.IsPressed` to `IsPressed`

Comment: Basically try to find some working triggers on web. My answer should contain only `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">` part, because it''s what you need to set the default style for `Button` control

Comment: Looks like this is something that i cannot use. I want to fire default click for any button from my view model.